# Python: Sorting X axis value manually

Tags: python, sorting, sqldf

I am trying to sort my x-axis on my graph as I believe my x-axis is not in an ascending order due to the data in my dataframe not being sorted properly. What I am seeing in my dataframe is"1,10,11,12 then 2,3,4..." Is there a way for me to sort my data into 1,2,3,4,5,6 or to be more specific, I would like to sort by the Month first, followed by Year, and lastly the destination. Codes and images as below.

```
q3a =  sqldf("SELECT Month, Year, TotalFlights, Month_Year, Destination FROM q3 
WHERE Destination = 'ABE' OR Destination = 'CSG' OR Destination = 'HLN' OR Destination = 'LAW' 
GROUP BY Destination, Year, Month 
ORDER BY Destination ASC, Year ASC, Month ASC")
pd.DataFrame(q3a)
```

Codes for my graph:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=q3a, col="Destination", col_wrap=2, height=6)
g = g.map(plt.plot, "Month_Year", "TotalFlights", marker=".")
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Apologies, I thought you were ordering based on Month.

Month_Year is of type `str` instead of type `int`. If you change your column variable to a numeric type, your code should sort the way you want it to. However your data in Month_Year is not exactly numeric...

Can you sort by your Year column, then Month? Otherwise a hacky solution would be to make a new column where *data = month + 12*year - 1* and sort from lowest to highest value.

Comment: yup, I’m aware my month_year is not exactly a numeric which is why for my another project that uses a different language, I manually keyed in the x axis so when i plot it it gives me what I want, and I sort by Year and Month but nope, still didn’t appear what I wanted, I’ll attempt the hacky solution 

Comment: The hacky solution should work. To explain it a little in math, 1/2004 would be 1 +12*2004 - 1 = 24048, 2/2004 would be 24049, ... , 12/2004 would be 24059, 1/2005 would be 24060. It moves by increments of 1.

Comment: so are you suggesting that I add a new column and do the maths inside and putting it in? And I sort by this new column?

Comment: Yes. You can write a for-loop for that. `df['new_column'] = [df['Month'][i] + 12*df['Year'][i] - 1 for i in df.index]`